# How to disable file input if we attach more than 1 file?

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to disable input field if it is more than one file. I'm new to file attachment. Can anyone help me - how to disable the input field?

this is the code:

```
fileChange = (e) => {
    var files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);
    var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
    console.log(filesArr);
    this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, ...filesArr] });
  }

<input
  id="fileUpolad"
  type="file"
  onChange={this.fileChange}
  accept="image/*"
  multiple
  disabled={this.state.files.length>1}
/>
```

Comment: It should be `disabled={this.state.files.length>1}`, you forgot `length`

Comment: @RonB. - i have given in my code but didn't worked. Sorry for typo

Comment: I see, it was a typo. May I ask what are you trying to achieve with `Array.prototype.slice.call`?

Comment: @RonB. - i'm achieving in this way ```FileList {0: File, length: 1, item: ƒ item(), constructor: Object}
0: File
length: 1
item: ƒ item() {}
<constructor>: "Function"
<constructor>: "FileList"```. Even the functionality is working without that code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can achieve the same thing you did with `Array.prototype.slice.call` by just doing `var filesArr = [...files];`

Second, I managed to solve your problem by having your `setState` function rely on the previous state like so:

```
 fileChange = (e) => {
    var files = e.target.files;
    console.log(files);
    var filesArr = [...files];
    console.log(filesArr);
    this.setState(prevState => ({ files: [...prevState.files, ...filesArr] }));
  };


  <input
          id="fileUpolad"
          type="file"
          onChange={this.fileChange}
          accept="image/*"
          multiple
          disabled={this.state.files.length > 1} />
```

Notice that you're not choosing the same file more than once, otherwise the event doesn't fire

Comment: - Thanks! this works :). Thanks for helping me :)